# While loading JNI library, how the mapping happens with the actual library name

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

We load any native library by using

```
System.loadLibrary("hello")
```

Now I came to know that this library name refers to **hello.dll for windows** 
and  **libhello.so for unix** based system.

So where these platform dependent changes happens?

Is JRE doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The platform dependent library name is built in native methods of the Java Virtual Machine.
The actual algorithm simply prepends/appends a platform specific prefix/suffix to the name:

- Windows: `"hello"` -> `"hello.dll"`
- Linux/Solaris: `"hello"` `"libhello.so"`
- Mac: `"hello"` -> `"libhello.dylib"`

**Long version:**

There are a couple of JDK Java methods which deal with loading libraries and/or library names:

```
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(String name)
java.lang.System.mapLibraryName(String name)
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(String name) 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(String name)
```

The famous `System.loadLibrary` actually calls `Runtime.loadLibrary` which calls `ClassLoader.loadLibrary`.
In the end the implementations of these methods call the following native methods which translate the given library name
into the platform specific name:

```
native java.lang.System.mapLibraryName(String name)
native java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.findBuiltinLib(String name)
```

The implementations of these native methods can be found in (link to the OpenJDK versions):

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c#l466
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/ClassLoader.c#l495

Both methods implement the same algorithm to build the actual library name,
prepending the prefix `JNI_LIB_PREFIX` and appending the suffix `JNI_LIB_SUFFIX`.

In the end the macros `JNI_LIB_PREFIX` and `JNI_LIB_SUFFIX` are defined in platform dependent include files, namely

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/javavm/export/jvm_md.h#l42
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/solaris/javavm/export/jvm_md.h#l43
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/javavm/export/jvm_md.h#l43

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

From the Javadoc for `loadLibrary`: "Loads the system library specified by the libname argument. The manner in which a library name is mapped to the actual system library is system dependent." `System.mapLibraryName(libname)` will return what the mapped library name will be.

This reflects the common conventions for library names: `lib` prefix in Linux and Mac OS X, no prefix in Windows, plus platform dependent file extension. Note that the extension for JNI libraries on Mac OS X is `jnilib`, not `dylib` as it is for other libraries. Also this mapping is not unique to the Java runtime, `gcc ... -lhello` will also look for `libhello.so` (or `libhello.dylib` on Mac OS X).

If you don't want the runtime to do this mapping, you'd have to determine the correct filename including the extension yourself and pass this to `loadLibrary`