# jni java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling existing methods in existing JDK lib

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I tried to call an existing native method, but get UnsatisfiedLinkError, and do not understand why since I copied existing code from the JDK and didn't wrote my own C function.

I copied some code from the JDK Sockets Java source code. Running on Ubuntu.

```
public class Sokket {

static {
    System.loadLibrary ("net");
}

static {
    initProto ();
}

// rest ommited for brevity
```

}

Running this code results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 

be.good.Sokket.initProto()V

at be.good.Sokket.initProto(Native Method)

at be.good.Sokket.<clinit>(Sokket.java:12)
```

I tried other native methods but same error, I changed the name of "net" to test if the library can be found and then I do get an error that that lib cannot be found in the `java.library.path`, I changed the name of "initProto" to test if the method can be found and then i do get the same error. So it looks to me that the "libnet.so" in the JDK lib directory has no initProto() but also no `createSocket()`.

When I run with `-verbose:jni` I do see a lot of libs loaded but no reference to "net" or "initProto".

How can I call existing native methods from my own code?

Comment: You should use `System.loadLibrary ("libnet");` . And, probably it is not a good idea to put it under the JDF folder.

Comment: The native symbol name is derived from the names of the package and class, so it will look for a function called `Java_be_good_Sokket_initProto`, which (probably) doesn't exist in that library. But, it does look like you can link the methods manually: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010645 (I've never tried that though)

Comment: @Daniele `"net"` on linux is mapped to `libnet.so` as a file name, so that part is correct.

Comment: @JornVernee not sure how that would work; of course you would not want to call `System.loadLibrary("libnet.so");`; since you need omit the `.so` suffix. In fact, `System.loadLibrary("net");` would look for a `net.so` file, which AFAIU is not mapped

Comment: @Daniele See this QA: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37203247

Comment: right.. thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @JornVernee: a big THANKS for pointing that out to me, will investigate on that further